# Is there a way to only pass the appended blob content to blob trigger Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I am trying to make a blob trigger azure function for log files, but the problem is it will pass through the entire blob content when any blob is created or updated.

So I am wondering is there a way to only get the appended blob content?

```
module.exports = async function main(context, myBlob) {
 // I am using javascript, myblob contains the entire content of single blob.
 // For logs in append blob, it results in duplicated logs, which is not ideal.
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I am wondering is there a way to only get the appended blob content?

No.

---

Unless you

- maintain the byte-index/position per log file where you read last some place (e.g. using a file/DB/any-persistant-storage) or [use Durable Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp)
- on change notification, you find the last byte-index/position and read starting from that location using appropriate SDK/API. [Here is the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/read) (for ADLS Gen2, find the right one if you're using Gen1 or Blob) and some description on how to [read a byte range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-file-service-operations) out of a file in blobs.